# Is there a script of St. Francis' "famous" speach in Bologna, the 15th of August of 1222?

Tags: history, resource-request, sermon, hagiography

I was reading a book about St. Francis and there is a mention about a "famous" speech he gave in the piazza of Bologna, the 15th of August of 1222. There are several descriptions around of this speech. For example, [this book](https://books.google.cl/books?id=yVG1oWcd1ScC&lpg=PA135&ots=EFy0P-Qmm_&dq=St%20francis%20preaching%20in%20bologna%2015%20august%201222&pg=PA135#v=onepage&q=St%20francis%20preaching%20in%20bologna%2015%20august%201222&f=false) mentions:

[image]

Footnote 69 above mentions [this page](https://www.dmgh.de/mgh_ss_29/index.htm#page/580/mode/1up) in Monumenta Germaniae Historica. The key passage is:

[image]

This text was originally published in [Historia Salonitana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_Salonitana) and can be found [here](https://books.google.cl/books?id=B6xNIF-9PmgC&lpg=PA386&ots=60g4M_9nNQ&dq=Historia%20Salonitana&pg=PA178#v=onepage&q&f=false), together with an English translation  (page 178 and 179 respectively).

I haven't however found the original sermon. [This blog entry](https://idlespeculations-terryprest.blogspot.com/2012/09/preaching-in-bologna-angels-people-and.html) seems to incorrectly state that the above document contains the full sermon.

Anyone aware of where can such sermon be found?

Comment: All I found so far were 3rd party accounts of his sermon, no transcript.  I do find an authoritative collection of all his writings translated and prepared in 1906 by Fr. Paschal Robinson, OFM based on earlier critical editions, and digitized [here](https://oll.libertyfund.org/titles/assisi-the-writings-of-saint-francis-of-assisi)